# Error pulling info from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, mapping

I am building a website that is run locally.

I have a database that looks like this:

```
  "posts":
        {
            "0":
                {

                    "count": 5
                },
            "1":
                {
                    "postID": 1,
                    "user": 1,
                    "showComments": false,
                    "date": 1451606400,
                    "upvotes": 127,
                    "downvotes": 6790,
                    "lat": 42.389825,
                    "long": -72.528267,
                    "commentsIDList": [1,2], // when implementing comments, store them by ID so they can be ontained easily
                    "postText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                },
}
```

I want to dynamically pull the 'postText' by mapping over the db entries. So far I have this:

```
<div className="feed-body">
              {this.state.postText[this.state.active].posts.map( (map, i) => {
                return (
                <Post key={i + (this.state.active * 1000)} parentId={this.state.posts[this.state.active].userID} data={map} />
                    );
                })}
                      </div>
```

However, every time I ran the main page doesnt load. When I remove this piece of code from my index.js file, everything works fine, except that nothing is pulled from the db. So I know the error is in this of code, I just don' know if I am pulling the right way.

Comment: Do you get an error somewhere? Check the console in the browser and in your backend

Comment: I cant find the error specifically. It only tells me it's on this line: <Post key={i + (this.state.active * 1000)} parentId={this.state.posts[this.state.active].userID} data={map} />

Comment: it's probably this thing `this.state.posts[this.state.active].userID` try to `console.log(this.state.posts)`, is it undefined?

Comment: what is inside `this.state.postText` and `this.state.posts`?

Comment: postText is inside posts, like in the database

Comment: postText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"?

Comment: @user_456059239 if there is an error try looking at the console to see it. In chrome right click -> inspect -> console.

Comment: this is the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)